# How to move links to the right with flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What is the best way to move the about and contact links to the right side of the navigation section?

I have tried using align-items: flex-end, however, for some reason it doesn't work.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}


/* Navigation */

.navigation-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.navigation-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Container -->
<div class="container">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div class="navigation-container">
    <span class="background"></span>
    <!-- Results Nav-->
    <span class="navigation-items" id="resultsNav">
      <h3>About</h3>
      <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;•&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h3>
      <h3>Contact</h3>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: align-items:flex-end works for me, is it possible you just made an grammar error?

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solutions:

Because you are already using position: fixed; you could just add     **right: 0;** to your .navigation-container to make it align to the right.

```
.navigation-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Or you can make your **navigation-container** element 100% wide. Then you can add some flex styles to it like this, to make the children align to the right.

```
.navigation-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a little jsfiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/wrayvon/akzfuvq8/4/

Using this styling:

```
.container {  position: relative;  display: flex;  margin-top: 5px;  margin-bottom: 25px;}
.navigation-container {  width: 100%;}
.navigation-items {  display: flex;  justify-content: flex-end;}
```

That solves it :)

Answer (score 0):

To assign end of the div parent should have 100% width. Just add the below CSS then it should work:

```
.navigation-container{
    width:100%;
}

.navigation-items{
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `flex-direction:column` then `justify-content` = vertical alignment and `align-items` = horizontal alignment.

As you can see in this example of your snippet. Align-items works as expected.

If you where adding align-items to a child of `.container` then you will not notice the change in alignment as the width of the child e.g `.navigation-container` needs to be (`flex:1`) to fill the width of its parent.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

/* Navigation */
.navigation-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.navigation-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Container -->
<div class="container">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div class="navigation-container">
    <span class="background"></span>
    <!-- Results Nav-->
    <span class="navigation-items" id="resultsNav">
      <h3>About</h3>
      <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;•&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h3>
      <h3>Contact</h3>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add `align-items: flex-end;` to the flex container.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}


/* Navigation */

.navigation-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.navigation-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Container -->
<div class="container">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <div class="navigation-container">
    <span class="background"></span>
    <!-- Results Nav-->
    <span class="navigation-items" id="resultsNav">
      <h3>About</h3>
      <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;•&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h3>
      <h3>Contact</h3>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```